# I cannot input a character. My program terminates

Tags: c

Here is my code for my project. It's not yet done because I'm stuck with the last `scanf` (after `printf("Enter option:")`). My program terminates after pressing two keys. I also tried char and %c but it didn't work. Hope you can help me.

```
void main()
{

    char user[20], pass[500];
    int i, a;
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(30,7); printf("ACCESS THE SYSTEM");
    gotoxy(28,9); printf("Username: ");
    gets(user);
    gotoxy(28,11); printf("Password: ");
    for(i = 0; i< 500; i++)
    {
        pass[i] = getch();
        if(pass[i] == 13)
        {
            pass[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        printf("*");
    }
    gotoxy(30,15);printf("ACCESS GRANTED!");
    gotoxy(24,20);printf("Please press any key to proceed: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    topics();
    getch();
}

int topics(){

    int opt;
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(25,5);printf("ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»");
    gotoxy(25,6);printf("º Computer Programming Topics: º");
    gotoxy(25,7);printf("ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼\n");
    gotoxy(13,9);printf("Choose one:");
    gotoxy(13,11);printf("[A] Conditional Statements");
    gotoxy(13,13);printf("[B] Looping Statements");
    gotoxy(13,15);printf("[C] Functions");
    gotoxy(13,17);printf("[D] Arrays");
    gotoxy(13,19);printf("[E] Strings");
    gotoxy(13,22);printf("Enter option:");
    gotoxy(13,23);scanf("%d", &opt);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: *never* use gets.  Use fgets instead.  gets remains in the language only for backwards compatibility and has been deprecated since...about 20 minutes before its first implementation.  Do not use it.

Comment: Actually, `gets` has been *removed* from the C standard.

Comment: The posted code seems to be a `ncurses` program.   An important detail is missing from the posted code.  Specifically, which header files are being #included?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &opt);` tries to read an *integer*, but the menu items you show are letters ('A' through 'E').

Answer (score 0):

given this code, in main()

```
    gotoxy(24,20);printf("Please press any key to proceed: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    topics();
    getch();
```

the line: `scanf("%d", &a); required the input to end with a 'return' key which puts a newline in the input stream, that is not consumed here.

the `topics()` function contains a `getch()` which does get the 'return' key from the input stream.

Note: a 'return' key is not a valid input for the `topics()` function.

then the user has to input another keystroke for the final `getch()` in main().  Then the execution runs off the end of main() which results in the program exiting.

Suggest:  in main() the line: `scanf("%d", &a);` be replaced with `getch()`

The posted code, after calling `topics()` (which gets a keystroke) then, one more keystroke and the program exits.

If you want the program to continue executing,  then the call to `topics()` needs to be followed by some other code to execute.